# Django Passing Context

Tags: django

I understand the code below will not work but I am hoping that it will give an understanding of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
def FilterTrackView(request,operation):
   today = datetime.now()
   if operation == today.date():
      raceDay = RaceDay.objects.filter(raceDayDate__date='2019-02-21')

      for race in raceDay:
        tracks += Track.objects.filter(id=race.raceDayVenue_id).values()


   return render(request, 'tracks/tracklist.html', {'tracks': tracks})
```

RaceDay Model

```
class RaceDay(models.Model):
  raceDayTitle = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  raceDayDate = models.DateField()
  raceDayStartTime = models.TimeField()
  raceDayVenue = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
  raceWeather = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Track Model

```
 class Track(models.Model):
   trackName = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   trackStatus = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Unknown")
```

Comment: Why do you think it won't work?

Comment: You have to assign something to tracks if `operation` is not today, otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: By looking at the script I think you need to obtain all the race data and the tracks data related to that race if operation is today. I think you need to submit your own models and views so that better understanding can be obtained. If there is relation between two models using foreign key then you may use `select_related`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been easier if you had actually *described* what you wanted to accomplish, rather than us trying to work it out from non-functional code, but it looks like you want all Tracks that are related to a certain RaceDay. That is easy enough:

```
tracks = Track.objects.filter(raceday__raceDayDate='2019-02-21')
```

(Note, there's rarely a good reason to use `values()`).

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to add multiple Track objects to tracks and pass it to my template.

Comment: And does this answer not do that?

Comment: Apologies, that does work. It must have been something to do with .values() as I tried this exact solution yesterday and it was just overwriting the value.

Comment: Can you also point me in the direction to learn more about "raceday__raceDayDate" I have not seen the underscore notation used before.

Comment: That's a really useful concept in Django queries: docs are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).